# Is it possible to get access to device container in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

In Xcode when I navigate to Window -> Devices I am able to download a container with application data. I often need that data in my project and find myself waisting a lot of time clicking through navigation to get it. I am interested to know if that part of application is available through code, can I get access to it through Swift, Objective-C or automator to create a script or plugin to automate this process.

Comment: The container is the app sandbox. Any app can access any file in its own sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

See [Locating Items in the Standard Directories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW3) for details.

Basic example:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
```